# convert RDD to Dataset in Java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have an RDD, i need to convert it into a Dataset, i tried:

```
Dataset<Person> personDS =  sqlContext.createDataset(personRDD, Encoders.bean(Person.class));
```

the above line throws the error,

> cannot resolve method createDataset(org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
>   Main.Person, org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder T)

however, i can convert to `Dataset` after converting to `Dataframe`. the below code works:

```
Dataset<Row> personDF = sqlContext.createDataFrame(personRDD, Person.class);
Dataset<Person> personDS = personDF.as(Encoders.bean(Person.class));
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`.createDataset()` accepts `RDD<T>` not `JavaRDD<T>`. `JavaRDD` is a wrapper around RDD inorder to make calls from java code easier. It contains RDD internally and can be accessed using `.rdd()`. The following can create a `Dataset`:

```
Dataset<Person> personDS =  sqlContext.createDataset(personRDD.rdd(), Encoders.bean(Person.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

on your rdd use `.toDS()` you will get a dataset.

Let me know if it helps. Cheers.

Comment: try something like, `Dataset<Row> personDS =  sqlContext.createDataFrame(personRDD, Person.class);`

Comment: its a `DataFrame`, but i need a `Dataset`

Comment: ya, it'll give you a dataset<Row>

Comment: `Dataset<Row>` is just an alias for `DataFrame`, `Dataset<Person>` is required. Not `Dataset<Row>`

Comment: *`DataFrame` is just an alias for `Dataset<Row>`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to accepted answer, if you want to create a `Dataset<Row>` instead of `Dataset<Person>` in Java, please try like this:

```
StructType yourStruct = ...; //Create your own structtype based on individual field types
Dataset<Row> personDS =  sqlContext.createDataset(personRDD.rdd(), RowEncoder.apply(yourStruct));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
StructType schema = new StructType()
                .add("Id", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("Name", DataTypes.StringType)
                .add("Country", DataTypes.StringType);

Dataset<Row> dataSet = sqlContext.createDataFrame(yourJavaRDD, schema);
```

Be carefull with schema variable, not always easy to predict what datatype you need to use, sometimes it's better to use just StringType for all columns