# How to convert Rdd to dataset using mapPartitions Function

Tags: java, apache-spark

I am trying to convert a java spark RDD to dataset.

According to spark doc. mapPartitions is faster than map function.

it will help to improve performance of spark.

Comment: Not convinced your assumptions and answer and question go hand in hand

Comment: Possible duplicate of [convert RDD to Dataset in Java Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45326796/convert-rdd-to-dataset-in-java-spark)

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41302666/converting-javardd-to-dataframe-in-spark-java

Answer (score 0):

Below Is java code.

```java
JavaRDD<UserData> UserRowRDD = userSuccessRDD.mapPartitions(new FlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>, UserData>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator call(Iterator<String> input) throws Exception {
                List<UserData> result = new ArrayList<>();
                while (input.hasNext()) {
                    result.add(Util.getEnrichedUser(UserHeader, input.next()));
                }
                return result.iterator();
            }
        });

public static UserData getEnrichedUser(String[] header, String rddString) {

                    String[] parts = rddString.split("\\^");
                    UserData output = new UserData();
                    for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
                        try {
                            BeanUtils.setProperty(output, header[i], parts[i]);
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    return output;

    }
```